# Sortable Column By Displayed Text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

So, I'm fairly new to rails and have inherited a large active rails project for development. The current bug I'm working on is rather fiddly and kinda complicated but basically, I have a list of users who can apply to various programs. Through the application process, a user's application status changes to many different things in the database (e.g. "applied", "pending","approved","denied", etc.). It is important that it stays this way for other functionality.  Now, there's a page that lists all of the users and their application status but the admins only want a boolean displayed (i.e. if it's anything other than approved it display's "Not Approved") which I have working correctly; however, if they sort the column, it is sorting by the database values, not by the displayed values and thus appears broken.
For example:

Not Approved (applied)  Approved (approved)  Not Approved (denied)  Not Approved (pending)

So is there a way to:

A)Weight the various statuses so all the "No's" appear together, or
B)Sort by the displayed values rather than the database values

I played with building a pure javascript solution but there's pagination on this list and javascript would only sort the visible page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either do this in a Ruby Level or Database Level.

If you do matter about performance so I think the db level will be the solution to go with.

Ruby LEVEL.

```
@users = User.all.sort_by { |u| u.status == 'approved' }
```

DB LEVEL.

```
User.all.order("(case when status = 'approved' then 0 else 1)")
```